# How to get exact location inside building?

Tags: android, geolocation, gps, foursquare

Is there any workaround get exact location inside building or still it's not possible..
I've checked few things like 
https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/venues
http://www.walkbase.com/
http://www.directionsmag.com/articles/10-things-you-need-to-know-about-indoor-positioning/324602

But didn't able to find what I want!!
I want my app to know weather user in in particular restaurant or not!! I'v also tried http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html
but not sure how to use it..
It'll be great if someone help me with where to start and which is best?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

no it is not possible. some companies experiment: for some buildings, that have to be measured to the specific technologiy that those companies use, it may work a bit, but not in general case.

if you want to know the restaurant, enable gps before the user enters the restaurant.
that way you get the position via gps when the user stands before the restaurants door.

as long as the restaurant is not inside a huge indoor shopping center, chances are good.

Comment: Okay, Can I know which service is more accurate than others? I particularly want My app to know if I'm in particular restaurant or not?

Comment: yes you can, Gps is always the most acurate, butmake sure that it is enable and not a hybrid mode. you can read out the location.getAccuracy in meters,

Comment: I've tried that but for some reasons I'm not getting GPS inside buildings, and without that the app is useless. Is FourSquare api useful for getting locations Or they are using the same GPS calss?? Btw Thanks for helping..

Comment: nobody get Gps inside a building, except near windows and then distorted. i would use android api to get the gps location as (latitude, longitude) once you have it decide yourself how to get the name of  the restaurant.